# How to update REST API Client from a Swagger file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest, swagger

How do I update a REST API Client from a Swagger file in Visual Studio?  I created my REST API Client via the "Add -> REST API Client" menu option when right-clicking on the project.  See screenshot below.  I now have an updated version of the Swagger file and need to also update the auto-generated client code.  How do I do this in Visual Studio?

I have not been able to find a way to update the auto-generated code without completely deleting the code first and then re-adding the REST API Client.  I am looking for something similar to the "Update Service Reference" functionality for a WSDL.

[image: Add REST API Client menu option]
[image: Add REST API Client popup]

Comment: That Rest API Client is a pain, the version they use is out of date and full of bugs, seems that Microsoft only updates it when there is a new version of Visual Studio, better use different swagger codegen tool.

Comment: I found and interesting post from the autorest team, "VS2017 integration uses a fixed version, so the best option is calling autorest directly" why they use a ***fixed version*** ? maybe a developer was in a rush : https://github.com/Azure/autorest/issues/2198

Comment: Note: With Visual Studio 2019 16.9.x, MS removed this generator and replaced it with an OpenAPI generator that doesn't even generate compileable code when having more than one controller class.

Comment: You must use the template value (is also default value in NSwagStudio) for controller name specification: **{controller}Client** when there is more than one controller class.

Comment: which template value?

Answer (score 3):

The menu option seems to be poorly named, but the act of Adding a REST API client actually overwrites/updates an existing client.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't overwrite/update the existing client.  Instead it created a new client with "1" appended to the end.

Comment: You're correct with regard to the "1" appended at the end of the client. I was able to replicate this issue using a locally-defined swagger file. If I add a REST API client using a swagger document url (download from the Azure portal) then new entry (with an appended "1") is not added to the project.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same problem and this worked for me.

1. Add -> REST API Client" menu option when right-clicking on the
   project.
2. Copy and paste the swagger url into "metadata file Swagger  Url"
3. At this point I was expecting the OK button to be enabled but it was
   not
4. Click on the button Select Azure Asset
5. Click return back
6. The OK button should be enabled
7. Click OK

This should regenerate the  existing client.
This is just a play-around but I was able to regenerate it without adding an extra client.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient solution for me is to use the command line for this case.

1. Install the `nswag` command line tool:

```shell
npm install nswag -g
```

2. Generate C# client code from a Swagger specification:

```shell
nswag openapi2csclient /input:MyWebService.json 
                       /classname:MyServiceClient 
                       /namespace:MyNamespace
                       /output:MyServiceClient.cs
```

The latest help on this command can be found here: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/CommandLine#client-generators